# Representation of integers as powers of the golden ratio

Tags: number-theory, golden-ratio

How to prove that any integer $n$ can be represented in the form  of
 $$n= \phi^{z_1}+\phi^{z_2}+\phi^{z_3}+...+\phi^{z_m}$$
For $z_1$, $z_2$... $z_m$ $\in$ $\mathbb Z $ and $\phi =\frac{ \sqrt 5+1}{2} .$

Comment: You'll want to make conditions to avoid trivial situations, like $z_1=\cdots=z_m=0$ and $n=m$. (Note $n<0$ cannot be represented in this form because $\phi$ is positive.)

Comment: Here's a hint: every positive integer has a (unique) representation as $\sum{\delta_i F_i}$ where the deltas are zero or one and $F_i$ is the ith Fibonacci number.

Comment: Ha, and I was thinking of $\sin$ forms of $\phi$ and then applying stuff like Kronecker-Weber!

Comment: As stated, all you need to do is show $\displaystyle 1=\sum_{k=1}^m \phi^{z_k}$. Then $\displaystyle n = \sum_{k=1}^{nm} \phi^{z_{k\text{ mod } m}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1 = \phi^0$$
$$1 = \phi^{-1} + \phi^{-2}$$
Note that $$\phi^{-n} = \phi^{-(n+1)} + \phi^{-(n+2)}$$
You may expand the sum onto any integers.